# Split/Copy/Move cell contents to pre-specified/corresponding columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following situation. In an Excel worksheet, I have a column which contains values that are separated by "|". 
e.g.

```
Option Column
Option 1 | Option 3
Option 4 | Option 7
Option 2 | Option 3 | Option 6
```

I want to

```
1. Insert 10 columns to the right, name them "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" ..... "Option 10"
2. In each cell of the first column, if "Option x" exists, split/copy/move to the column named "Option x" (Where x can be 1, 2 .... 10)
```

[image]

This is the code that I use currently to achieve it:

```
   Sub Insert_10_columns()
    Columns("B:K").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    For i = 2 To 11
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = "Option " & i - 1
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Look_For_Text()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow + 1
        For k = 1 To 10
            If InStr(1, (Cells(i, 1).Value), "Option " & k) > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, k + 1).Value = "Option " & k
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

I was just wondering if loops are the best way to go about it, especially because when I start using it, I would be operating on 20,000+ rows and 15+ columns.

Comment: It's always much quicker to do the heavy lifting in arrays and only write back to the sheet once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant using `System.Collections.ArrayList` and `Scripting.Dictionary`, I guess that should be faster than your solution)

```
Sub test()
    Dim data As Range, cl As Range, i&, x As Variant
    Dim arrList As Object, Dic As Object
    Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set data = Range([A2], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    'get unique values from split
    For Each cl In data
        For Each x In Split(cl, "|"): x = Trim(x)
            If Not Dic.exists(x) Then
                Dic.Add x, Nothing
                arrList.Add x
            End If
    Next x, cl

    Dic.RemoveAll        'clear dictionary

    arrList.Sort         'sort values
    If sortorder = xlDescending Then
        arrList.Reverse
    End If

    'add headers
    i = 2
    For Each x In arrList
        Cells(1, i).Value2 = x
        Dic.Add x, i: i = i + 1
    Next x
    'split values against headers
    For Each cl In data
        For Each x In Split(cl, "|"): x = Trim(x)
            Cells(cl.Row, Dic(x)).Value2 = x
    Next x, cl
End Sub
```

**test here**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
I tried it on a heavier dataset and is definitely faster than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a loop to walk through while you split the cell contents. Looping through an array is faster than looping through the worksheet. After splitting, populate a target array with matching columns before putting the target array values into the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertOptions()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, mx As Long, dlm As String
    Dim hdrs As Variant, opts As Variant, vals As Variant, tmp As Variant, m As Variant

    dlm = " | "   'column A delimiter; might be " | "
    mx = 15       'maximum number of options

    With Worksheets("sheet9")

        'create an independent array of header labels
        ReDim hdrs(1 To 1, 1 To mx)
        For i = LBound(hdrs, 2) To UBound(hdrs, 2)
            hdrs(1, i) = "Option " & i
        Next i

        'collect the delimited options from column A
        opts = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2

        'make room for all options in expanded form
        ReDim vals(LBound(opts, 1) To UBound(opts, 1), _
                   LBound(hdrs, 2) To UBound(hdrs, 2))

        'loop through delimited options, split them and look for matches in hdrs
        For i = LBound(opts, 1) To UBound(opts, 1)
            tmp = Split(opts(i, 1), dlm)
            For j = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
                m = Application.Match(tmp(j), hdrs, 0)
                If Not IsError(m) Then
                    vals(i, m) = tmp(j)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        'insert ten new columns
        .Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, UBound(hdrs, 2)).EntireColumn.Insert

        'put arrays into new columns
        With .Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, UBound(hdrs, 2)).EntireColumn
            .ColumnWidth = 9
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(hdrs, 1), UBound(hdrs, 2)) = hdrs
            .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```